# css: How to change row color of a table after its been selected and clicked away

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-css

I have .css when the row is selected which is fine.

[image: row when clicked]

However when I click off the row it changes the row color grey with a black font, is there any way to edit this css?

[image: row when clicked off]

```
.table-view {
    -fx-base: transparent;
    -fx-control-inner-background: transparent;
    -fx-background-color: #507CA6;
    -fx-padding: 5;
}

.table-view .column-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view .column-header, .table-view .filler {
    -fx-size: 35;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: #B4D9FD;
    -fx-border-insets: 0 10 1 0;
}

.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-alignment: center-left; 
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}

.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled:focused:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #273D51;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your HTML & CSS look like?

Comment: If you're using CSS you have the following selectors `:active` `:focus` `:hover`. Yes, please post your code.

Comment: *at least* post your code...

Comment: @AndreaLigios sorry completely forgot to add it, my bad.

Comment: @MLeFevre apologies thought I added it.

Comment: Remove the last rule. End of story

Comment: @AndreaLigios not end of story i'm afraid, the grey row is still there when you click off the table

Comment: Guys sorry, the question is about CSS in JavaFX. So edited tag..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
/* When control is selected but not focused */
.table-row-cell:filled:selected,
.table-row-cell:filled > .table-cell:selected {
    -fx-background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first make selected class than use this script, i always use this **$("tr").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});​**